# How to kickout in a foreach loop?

Tags: php

For example in a for loop you can kick out like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($ary); $i++){
    if($ary[$i] == 'blah') 
        $i = count($ary);

    echo $i;
}
```

Or in a while loop:

```
$i = 0;

while($i < count($ary)){
    if($ary[$i++] == 'blah')
        $i = count($ary);

    echo $i;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by the term 'kickout'?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: remove that `count($ary)` from your loop and store it in a temp variable. Otherwise the function is executed on **every iteration of the loop**, which is really bad for performance: `$l = count($ary); while($i < $l)...`

Comment: I was looking for break; Thanks though for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure really what you mean by "kick out", but:

- To skip to the next item, use `continue;`
- To stop the entire loop, use `break;`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly what you are looking for is the `break` keyword.

[PHP Break](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use `break`

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($ary); $i++){
    if($ary[$i] == 'blah') 
        break;

    echo $i;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($ary); $i++){
    if($ary[$i] == 'blah') 
         break;

    echo $i;
}

foreach($ary as $c){
    if($c=='blah')break;
}
```

[Manual](http://php.net/break)